# How to compare two dataframe and fill the column value based on condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am trying to compare two dataframe based on some condition and trying to fill the column value. I am not getting desirable result. Could you please help me?

Example:

```
df1:

PDF_FILE_Name                                         Indication
PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_rfa_rec      
PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_rfa_cgr
PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_fdk_pfizer
PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_fdk_kcc


df2:

PDF_FILE_Name                                         Indication
PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_rfa_rec      Metastatic Renal Cell Carcinoma  
PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_fdk_pfizer   Metastatic Renal Cell Carcinoma

In result I want below df
print(df1):

PDF_FILE_Name                                         Indication
PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_rfa_rec      Metastatic Renal Cell Carcinoma  
PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_rfa_cgr
PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_fdk_pfizer   Metastatic Renal Cell Carcinoma
PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_fdk_kcc
```

Comment: Did you try Merge? `df1.merge(df2,on='PDF_FILE_Name',how='left')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple case of `merge()`

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""PDF_FILE_Name                                         Indication
PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_rfa_rec      
PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_rfa_cgr
PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_fdk_pfizer
PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_fdk_kcc"""), sep="\s+")

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""PDF_FILE_Name                                         Indication
PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_rfa_rec      Metastatic Renal Cell Carcinoma  
PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_fdk_pfizer   Metastatic Renal Cell Carcinoma
"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

df1.loc[:,["PDF_FILE_Name"]].merge(df2, on="PDF_FILE_Name", how="left")
```

|  | PDF_FILE_Name | Indication |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_rfa_rec | Metastatic Renal Cell Carcinoma |
| 1 | PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_rfa_cgr | nan |
| 2 | PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_fdk_pfizer | Metastatic Renal Cell Carcinoma |
| 3 | PA0001000_pcodr_rfa_axitinib_inlyta_mrcc_fdk_kcc | nan |

Answer (score 0):

`Series.map()`

```py
df1['Indication'] = df1['PDF_FILE_Name'].map(df2.set_index('PDF_FILE_Name')['Indication'])
```

Or `merge()`

```py
df1['Indication'] = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='PDF_FILE_Name')['Indication_y']
```